# Internet Explorer restringiu execução de scripts

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Sempre que abro a página HTML no IE aparece-me a seguinte mensagem:

> o internet explorer restringiu a execução de scripts ou controles activex

Para a pagina aparecer correctamente tenho de activar isso. Existe alguma forma de corrigir isso no próprio HTML?

Para corrigir o MODO do Browser dá para corrigir também pelo HTML?

Encontrei [isto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488370/can-i-avoid-the-internet-explorer-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts) mas não percebi muito bem esta solução.

Index.html

```
<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/init.js"></script>
<noscript>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-wide.css" />
</noscript>
<!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: Tem, não use ActiveX.

Comment: Não existe outra forma?

Comment: Que eu saiba, não. Isto é algo perigoso e o usuário precisa ser alertado disto. Ele precisa autorizar sua execução explicitamente. Existe a possibilidade dele configurar o IE para não dar este aviso, mas isto é opção do usuário não do desenvolvedor da página. E não recomendo ninguém fazer. Não sei nem se deveria ter a opção. O novo navegador da Microsoft sequer irá permitir que ActiveX rode de tão ruim que ele é.

Comment: Seria interessante você dizer qual funcionalidade pretende obter com isso. Provavelmente existe uma maneira melhor de resolver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A única forma de disto não aparecer é não usar ActiveX. Este tipo de tecnologia é perigoso para o usuário e só existe ainda por questões legadas.

Como há risco o usuário pelo menos é avisado disto e só ele pode determinar se pode ou não executar algo que pode colocá-lo em risco.

Eventualmente o usuário pode configurar o navegador para não informar disto, mas é uma decisão dele e nada recomendada. Nenhum desenvolvedor de páginas consegue interferir nisto.

A tecnologia é tão legada que o navegador principal do Windows 10 não contará com ela. Ainda existirá o Internet Explorer para rodar essas tecnologias legadas, mas ele provavelmente não terá mais novas atualizações no futuro.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Correcto. Mas está página apenas será para utilizar na forma de intranet e será só para está página. Encontrei isto mas nao percebi muito bem .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488370/can-i-avoid-the-internet-explorer-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts

Comment: porque que o unico Browser a queixar disso é o IE?

Comment: Provavelmente porque eles nem tentam executar. O que eu estou achando é que você está usando algo que nem sabe como funciona. Você deve entender as coisas antes de usar. Com a informações que você deu na pergunta não é possível identificar nenhum problema além disto.

Comment: O Layout do site foi tirado da internet. Mas a unica forma de por o site a funcionar no IE é activando esse Script ou controlador de ActiveX.

Comment: Você jamais deve colocar no seu *site* algo que você não conhece. Principalmente se a origem e confiabilidade for duvidosa. E nem estou falando de pegar de fontes inconfiáveis, porque isto é óbvio que não deveria. Também nem estou questionando se o que você pegou pode ser usado, se não infringe direitos de quem fez, estou entendendo que você tem autorização para pegar. Você está dizendo coisas que não temos como saber. Por isto não há como responder melhor que isto. Duvido que esta seja a única forma.

Comment: Correcto, Mas apenas aproveitei o Layout e coloquei todas as informações que queria. No site em questão (http://html5up.net/) tem download Free dá página.
Já de nada utilizei o Site que diz Arcana.

Comment: Não abre. Grande parte das coisas grátis disponíveis na internet tem algum interesse oculto. Muitos dos *scripts* disponíveis na internet são cavalos de tróia. Vou falar mais uma vez, não use o que você não conhece.

Comment: O que não abre? (http://html5up.net) Já utilizei varias vezes este site para outras coisas .

Comment: Tem hora que abre, hora não. Já lhe falei tudo o que dava sobre o assunto. Só posso dizer que além disto, você pode estar usando errado, mas a pergunta não mostra detalhes suficientes para dar uma resposta mais detalhada.

Comment: Coloquei informações sobre o index do Site