# Mensagem de Segurança sobre controle ActiveX

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Sistema: Windows 8 e Microsoft Office 2013

Estou tendo problemas com uma tela de alerta sobre controle ActiveX que vem me perturbando a algum tempo:

Antes de abrir o Form onde está o controle Windows Media Player, aparece uma tela de advertência com o seguinte texto:

"Este aplicativo está prestes a inicializar controles ActiveX que podem não ser seguros. Se você confia na origem deste arquivo, selecione OK e os controles serão inicializados usando as configurações atuais do espaço de trabalho."

Esta mensagem somente aparece uma única vez, antes da abertura do UserForm
Projetos sem o controle Windows Media Player a citada tela de advertência não aparece.

Em mais de uma oportunidade, realizei exaustiva pesquisa sobre o assunto na internet mas;, nada encontrei para resolver o problema.
Confesso que já tentei de tudo para sumir com ela, mas esgotei as possibilidades

> Já alterei de diversas formas a Segurança de Macros sem sucesso
>   Ja alterei alguns registros em  < regedit - HKEY_CURRENT_USER e também em HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, seguindo orientações encontradas em sites, também sem sucesso
>   Na verdade, pesquisando na internet, até se encontra alguma coisa sobre o assunto, mas baseado em versões do windows/office mais antigas

Conto com a atenção da comunidade para a solução do problema

Comment: [Esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49103/internet-explorer-restringiu-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-scripts/49160#49160) fala de ActiveX no browser, mas traz informações úteis. Talvez não haja como controlar isso.

Answer (score 1):

Criei um exemplo aqui (excel 2013, windows 8), e em um form coloquei o mesmo controle "WindowsMediaPlayer" e alterei os registro conforme a terceira resposta deste [exemplo](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/212739-userform-microsoft-spreadsheet-control-activex-warning.html) e a mensagem não aparece mais.

Obs: No link de exemplo fiz somente os 16 primeiros passos (ActiveX), pois os demais eram sobre macros e assinatura)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Este questionamento também foi postado em:
social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/53fa380d-464f-44f2-bb74-d82a860c996c/mensagem-de-segurana-sobre-controle-activex?forum=vbapt&prof=required
e felizmente foi respondido pelo Felipe Costa Gualberto, que postou a seguinte solução:

Crie uma Chave em HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VBA\ chamada Security
Em Security, crie um registro DWORD chamado LoadControlsInForms e como valor coloque 4.

Isto foi testado por mim e funcionou perfeitamente.
Espero igualmente ter colaborado com a comunidade.

Valmor